# creating svg elements with angularJS

Tags: svg, angularjs

I'm trying to create an svg element with angular. Currently I'm able to do an ng-repeat but when I try to assign values to my attributes I get an error.

```
<g ng-repeat="cell in row">
    <rect x="{{cell.node.x}}" y="{{cell.node.y}}"></rect>
    <text x="10" y="10">{{cell.node.name}}</text>
</g>
```

Interesting enough cell.node.name does work and shows the name nicelly but cell.node.x and cell.node.y, give me the following error accordingly
Error: Invalid value for attribute x="cell.node.x" Error: Invalid value for attribute y="cell.node.y" 
Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem. Seems angular and SVG don't mix very well at this point.

Comment: I just published an article on working with AngularJS + SVG. I discuss some of the problems and how to avoid or workaround them. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709340/Implementing-a-Flowchart-with-SVG-and-AngularJS

Comment: Jarnal's answer is now (and for a while) the better answer

Comment: @AshleyDavis, Thank you very much, I was able to write my own directive for flow chart, following your blog.

Comment: Jarnal's answer is definitely the best now. Solved it for me!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The newer versions of Angular feature ngAttr attribute bindings, which should avoid the errors caused when the browser validates before Angular kicks in.

Example (from [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)):

```
<svg>
  <circle ng-attr-cx="{{cx}}"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: hmm... I wonder if it will ever be a replacement for d3js. Thanks for sharing Jarnal!

Comment: As-of `angular 1.3.10` `ng-attr-viewBox` and other camelCase attributes don't work because ng-attr lowercases the attribute (ie `viewbox=...` doesn't work).

Comment: Even in the case of camelCase SVG attributes, Angular has a way. instead of `ng-attr-viewBox`, write `ng-attr-view_box`. Then when Angular goes to denormalize the attribute ready for SVG, it knows to capitalize the letter after the underscore.This comes from a bit lower down in the same [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that Jarnal was referring to in his answer.

Comment: I was looking for exactly this @daemonaka. Where do you even find this? i've looked everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's working, [here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SCHnPz), but you're getting that error because the browser is validating the SVG before it renders it, and at the time of validation, x and y are equal to "{{cell.node.x}}" and "{{cell.node.y}}" respectively.  Once angular updates the view, it will indeed put the rectangles where they're supposed to be.

One thing I noticed though, is you're missing the `width` and `height` attributes on the rectangle, **which will cause them not to show.**

There aren't a lot of good ways to suppress this error. I suppose you could make a custom directive that didn't render the SVG elements until after they'd been $compiled.

Comment: Thank you very much blesh! Yeah after looking around I saw in the angular google group something regarding this as well. I think if I create the x and y attributes with directives angular will kick in. Yes indeed I'm missing the width and height to but I did not put them in for this example just because I didn't want to add more stuff to it.

Answer (score 0):

As blesh hints: making custom directives for the attributes that cause the problem stops the errors in Chrome. There's a solution in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1050#issuecomment-9650293) on github.