# Unexpected value {{specs.height}} parsing height attribute. index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-ng-repeat

**I am practicing responsive SVGs with angularjs**
I try to draw a rectangular barchart using ng-repeat but only one displayed and the others keep springing out error.

Here is what I tried:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Angular Charts</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dashboard = angular.module("Dashboard", []);

    dashboard.controller("BarGraphController", function($scope) {
      $scope.specs = {
        height: 30,
        bars: [{
          color: '#2a9fbc',
          width: 50
        }, {
          color: '#f15b2a',
          width: 70
        }, {
          color: '#a62e5c',
          width: 100
        }]
      };
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="Dashboard">
  <div ng-controller="BarGraphController">
    <span>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250" style="border:solid 1px gray">
                    <rect ng-repeat="bar in specs.bars" 
                        x="0" y="0" fill="{{bar.color}}" width="{{bar.width}}" height="{{specs.height}}"/>
                </svg>
            </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here is what I keep getting in my browser:

> Unexpected value {{specs.height}} parsing height attribute. index.html
>   Unexpected value {{bar.width}} parsing width attribute. index.html
>   Unexpected value {{specs.height}} parsing height attribute. angular.min.js:70:379
>   Unexpected value {{bar.width}} parsing width attribute. angular.min.js:70:379
>   Unexpected value {{specs.height}} parsing height attribute. angular.min.js:70:379
>   Unexpected value {{bar.width}} parsing width attribute. angular.min.js:70:379
>   Unexpected value {{specs.height}} parsing height attribute. angular.min.js:70:379
>   Unexpected value {{bar.width}} parsing width attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the rectangles are being displayed, but they are on top of one another.  Try setting your "y" attribute on the rect like this:

```
<rect ng-repeat="bar in specs.bars" 
                    x="0" y="{{$index * specs.height}}" fill="{{bar.color}}" width="{{bar.width}}" height="{{specs.height}}"/>
```

This should space them all out by the height you specified so you can see all of them.

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mhrhc19k/

See this thread for the errors you're getting: [creating svg elements with angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610915/creating-svg-elements-with-angularjs)

Looks like there may be an angular attribute you can use to avoid the errors.  The svg is rendering before angular is loaded so it's actually seeing {{specs.height}} instead of 30. That's the reason for the errors but it's still loading it later.  Might be time to create a directive :)