# Angular js Bind a variable into tag <text x =

Tags: html, css, angularjs, svg

I am trying to pass a value within my scope into the text tag for the x:

```
<g transform="translate(150,40)">
  <rect ng-style="{'width':info}" height="39" fill="#66CC99"></rect>
  <text x={{info}} y="9.5" dy="1.2em" dx="-5px">{{infoNum}}</text>
</g>
```

But I get the error:

```
> Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "{{info…".
```

How can I solve this issue? Is there a way to bind correctly a variable into x parameter? The approach: `ng-style="{'x':info}"` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ng-attr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes).

```html
<text ng-attr-x="{{info}}" y="9.5" dy="1.2em" dx="-5px">{{infoNum}}</text>
```

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301533/878514).